# Laravel 5.2 update datas

Tags: database, laravel

I use Laravel 5.2 a few day ago, and I've a problem!
I hope, somebody can help me.

I want a special proceedings, so I don't use resource.
My problem, the user's datas doesn't update in database, I try this a lots of ways, but nothing.

Here is my controller:

```
protected function edit($name)
    {
        return view('user.edit', array('user' => User::findByUsernameOrFail($name)));
    }

    protected function update($name, ProfileDataRequest $request)
    {
        $profile = User::findorfail($name);

        $input = $request -> all();

        $profile->update($input);

        return redirect()->action('UserController@show');
    }
```

My form:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['UserController@update', $user -> name ]]) !!}

         {{ csrf_field() }}

         {!! Form::label('sms', 'SMS: ') !!}
         {!! Form::checkbox('sms', 1, false) !!}

         {!! Form::label('name', 'Name: ') !!}
         {!! Form::text('name') !!}



         {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/user/{name}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('/user/{name}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
Route::patch('/user/{name}', 'UserController@update');
```

My request file:

```
class ProfileDataRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'sms' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

If you have a more simple method, please write to me!

Comment: Is there any error? Does the application enter update function?

Comment: If I click the submit button, just refresh the page, and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller methods are `protected` they should be `public` to be accessible.

replace `protected` to `public`

```
public function update(Request $request) {
   //your code here
}
```

[**Laravel Http Controller**](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers)